# How to enable ChatKit CKMadridService in jailbreaked iOS 5?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm writing an app like wifiSMS,but CKMadridService is always disabled.

```
NSLog(@"is madrid service supported ?  %hhd , Enabled? %hhd ",[CKMadridService isMadridSupported] ,[CKMadridService isMadridEnabled] );
```

how can i enable CKMadridService ?

Comment: I get a CKMadridService share instance ,and try to send a iMessage,but  
it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at ChatKit disassembly, `isMadridEnabled` is checking caller app bundle identifier. It will return true only if bundle ID equals to `com.apple.MobileSMS` or `com.apple.springboard`. So you could try to inject your dylib into springboard in order to send iMessages this way. I don't know for sure but at least `isMadridEnabled` should return true.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try hooking CKMadridService and return YES always, maybe this will allow you to send messages from within any process

Comment: I don't think hooking this method is the solution. Almost every CKMadridService method is using `BOOL CKIsRunningInMessagesOrSpringBoard()` function and several others instead of `isMadridEnabled` method. It's the same function that `isMadridEnabled` is using. So the solution is to hook following functions - `CKIsRunningInFullCKClient`, `CKIsRunningInMessagesOrSpringBoard`, `CKIsRunningInSpringBoard`. This way ChatKit will think that calling app is the springboard. Or you could hook `CKIsRunningInMessages` instead of `CKIsRunningInSpringBoard` to make him think that you are the Messages app.

Comment: @creker ,thanks for your helpful answers, I will hook these methods . And I am wondering how to inject dylib to SpringBoard, just put it in /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries , MobileSubstrate will load it automatically?